# Issue in configuring react SASS .module.scs files with laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-5

I am using react with laravel, can't get sass files to load. I have written my css/sass as modules (component.module.css) and stored the scss with the related react component js in a folder of there own (as you dod with components in react). and use....

```
import styles from './Compoent.module.scs';
```

I installed npm install node-sass as the app did not load sass files.

I noticed the "sass" folder in "resources" and placed a scss from one of the modules in there - did not work. I also copy and pasted it into the file call app.scs which is pre-installed into the folder. Ihis also did not work.

This is my webpack:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.browserSync('localhost:8000');
```

I have search through google and laravel but not much discussion on this issue.
Is there a set procedure i should follow?php artisan preset react was done after install.

Thanks for help.